# Limit checkbox and calculate between 2 active input fields

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to calculate the %share which is simply an addition of share1+share2 == 100. However, I want it to work only on the two checked checkboxes.

How do I go about detecting the selected checkbox and apply the function accordingly?

```js
var MAX = 2;
$('input.addnominee').click(function() {
    ($('input.addnominee:checked').length == MAX) ? $('input.addnominee').not(':checked').attr('disabled',true):$('input.addnominee').not(':checked').attr('disabled',false);
});
$("#share1").focusout(function() {
  var share1 = $("#share1").val();
  var answer = 100 - share1;
  $("#share2").val(answer);
});
$("#share2").focusout(function() {
  var share2 = $("#share2").val();
  var answer = 100 - share2;
  $("#share1").val(answer);
});
```

```css
label {
  display: block;
}
.block {
  background-color: #eee;
  padding: 15px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h6>You can choose a maximum of 2 users</h6>
<div class="block">
  <label class="checkbox"> Add User
    <input class="addnominee" type="checkbox" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#fnominee">
  </label>
  <div class="form-group">
    <input type="number" pattern="[0-9]*" id="share1" class="form-control" placeholder="% share" required>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="block">
  <label class="checkbox"> Add User
    <input class="addnominee" type="checkbox" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#fnominee">
  </label>
  <div class="form-group">
    <input type="number" pattern="[0-9]*" id="share2" class="form-control" placeholder="% share" required>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="block">
  <label class="checkbox"> Add User
    <input class="addnominee" type="checkbox" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#fnominee">
  </label>
  <div class="form-group">
    <input type="number" pattern="[0-9]*" id="share3" class="form-control" placeholder="% share" required>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="block">
  <label class="checkbox"> Add User
    <input class="addnominee" type="checkbox" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#fnominee">
  </label>
  <div class="form-group">
    <input type="number" pattern="[0-9]*" id="share4" class="form-control" placeholder="% share" required>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a specific reason to use `focusout`?

You could catch the ID's of the two "selected" elements inside your checkbox function. Or to be precise, get `id` of `input` that is in the next `div` inside the clicked checkbox's `parent`:

```
var active1, active2;
var MAX = 2;
$('input.addnominee').click(function() {
    ($('input.addnominee:checked').length == MAX) ? $('input.addnominee').not(':checked').attr('disabled',true):$('input.addnominee').not(':checked').attr('disabled',false);
    let checked = $('input.addnominee:checked');
    active1 = $(checked[0]).parent().next('div').children('input').attr('id');
    //Let's assign active2 only if we have multiple selected checkboxes:
    if(checked.length > 1) active2 = $(checked[1]).parent().next('div').children('input').attr('id');
});
```

Here's example with `click`. To simplify it a bit, I added `stepper` class into every number input, and we're now detecting click for the class `stepper`:

```
$(document).on('click','.stepper',function(){
    if($(this).attr('id') == active1){ //Check which one user clicked
        if(active2 != undefined){ //Make the math only if we have another active element
            var share1 = $('#'+active1).val();
            var answer = 100 - share1;
            $('#'+active2).val(answer);
        }
    }else if($(this).attr('id') == active2){
        if(active1 != undefined){
            var share2 = $('#'+active2).val();
            var answer = 100 - share2;
            $('#'+active1).val(answer);
        }
    }
});
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/xpvt214o/677733/

This surely works also with `focusout`, but you need to remember that clicking stepper wont focus the input, so it wouldn't be very functional.

And with this same idea you could also disable the inputs which are not 'active'. 
I hope this helps!

EDIT:

Maybe a bit simplified version with the same idea:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    var MAX = 2;
    $('input.addnominee').click(function() {
        ($('input.addnominee:checked').length == MAX) ? $('input.addnominee').not(':checked').attr('disabled',true):$('input.addnominee').not(':checked').attr('disabled',false);
    });
    $(document).on('click','.stepper',function(){
        var checked = $('input.addnominee:checked');
        if(checked.length > 1){
            var active1 = $(checked[0]).parent().next('div').children('input');
            var active2 = $(checked[1]).parent().next('div').children('input');
            var share = $(this).val();
            var answer = 100 - share;
            if($(this).attr('id') == $(active1).attr('id')){
                $(active2).val(answer);
            }else if($(this).attr('id') == $(active2).attr('id')){
                $(active1).val(answer);
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/128uzmj3/